# How to take control of a website you own?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, administration

I have a fiend who had some one else build his website for his store. He had lost his contact with the person who made it and doesn't know who is the web host. What are his options?
There is nothing on his website with a link for this or clue I could find.

Update: Found the host is weebly.com still no help without the email and password.

Comment: Bad administration leads to bad consequences. It's unlikely contacting the website host will do anything because it sounds like the hosting isn't in your friends name anyway but if you would like to find out yourselves then you can use [who hosts this](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/) which will identify most website hosting companies.

Comment: @SimonHayter that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also see not many options but one which comes to mind.

**If you don't have access to domain name:**
If you registered a domain name rather than sub-domain then you can possible back-order the domain once it's expired and becomes available then you simply reorder it and create sample site in different hosting you own.(there are tools copying sites)

**If you have access to domain name:** Then you can rebuild site in different hosting and point the name servers to the new hosting.